# NoScript stopped working after update to 11 (UnSolved)

Tags: update, noscript

Update #2

After Disabling the "HTTPS Everywhere" Extension I was unable to remove it.

So I deleted the TOR folder and downloaded the latest version (11) and reinstalled it to a new location.

Once again NoScript would not work and once again the HTTPS Everywhere extension is installed and I cannot remove it. Disabling it does once more cause NoScript to start working normally again.

Quesion #1 Why is the "HTTPS Everywhere" extension automatically installed?

Question #2 Does enabling "HTTPS-Only Mode" in the security settings work without the extension enabled?

```
Update #1: After digging through the security settings I changed a few
things and the issue is gone.

#1 Settings > Privacy and Security > HTTPS-Only Mode.

I've never seen this before and it was set to "Don't Enable". I've
always used the "HTTPS Everywhere" extension with TOR.

I changed the setting to "Enable in all windows" and then Disabled the Extension and restarted the browser. 

NoScript is functioning normal now.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Original Post:

Title says it. I just installed the V11 update to the TOR browser and
NoScript is no longer functioning as in it no longer blocks any
scripts.

After installing I had the same "missing bookmarks" bug I had when I
updated my regular Firefox ESR.

I followed the same steps I did for Firefox, deleting the
"favicons.sqlite" and "places.sqlite" files in my profile folder then
rebooting my PC.

That restored my bookmarks and then I noticed noscript was no longer
working in TOR. (It is still working in Firefox ESR)
```

Comment: You should have posted it as an answer, not as an edit to your question. Now, somebody in the future will search for a similar problem and will see that there is a question but no answer, so they won't check the link. After that you can also select your own answer.

Comment: Will do, once I get his figured out.

Comment: Its not working for me either, neither is ublock origin after the recent update (in fact it would not even display correctly, looked hollowed out, and menu items missing). Looks like this release was botched completely

Comment: Even after downloading and installing a fresh copy of tor, noscript is broken.

Comment: Even the latest alphas noscript's are broken, putting the entire network at huge risk. the options menu won't even open. this looks intentional

Comment: @Tyler Disable the 'HTTPS Everywhere' Extension for now. That will let NoScript function.

Like I said in my last update, I'm not even sure why it's there since there is a 'HTTPS-Only Mode" in the settings.